# How to change svg viewport programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, viewport

It is necessary to implement moving of ALL images inside of svg object. I plan to handle mouse events (down, move, up) and change viewport of svg (using JavaScript + probably jQuery).

The problem for me is I don't see how to change svg viewport parameters.

Please advise.

P.S. If you know something similar implemented already, please share the link. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery SVG lets you do this

svg.configure({viewBox: '0 0 100 100'}, true);

http://keith-wood.name/svgRef.html#configure